# Merging 2 large data sets in R

Tags: r, merge, large-data

I am trying to merge two large data sets as i need to create a final trainset for my models to run

```
head(TrainWithAppevents_rel4)    
event_id  |device_id |gender |age |group| phone_brand |device_model| numbrand nummodel | app_id    
6   6 1476664663289716480      M  19  M22-      åŽä¸º       Mate 7       29      919  4348659952760821248
```

and

```
head(app_labels)    
   app_id |label_id    
1  7324884708820028416        251
```

The first dataset has unique rows now as i have worked on it to remove all duplicates

i want my final set to be having the below columns

`event_id  device_id gender age group phone_brand device_model numbrand nummodel               app_id    label_id`

However when i try to merge using the below in R (R studio session)

```
TrainWithLabels=merge(x=TrainWithAppevents_rel4,y=app_labels,by="app_id",all.x = TRUE)
```

i get following error

`**Error: cannot allocate vector of size 512.0 Mb**`

Error varies if i run again but only in terms of size of vector

The sizes of my datasets are as below :

```
> dim(TrainWithAppevents_rel4)
[1] 4787796      10    
> dim(app_labels)
[1] 459943      2
```

More information about the machine/R i use :

```
> sessionInfo()    
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

i use intel 2.6GHz/16GB RAM /64 Bit OS/Windows10/x64 -based processesor

i have  tried the following :

-Reducing the dataset by removing duplicates and unwanted columns ,
   all rows in the first dataset are unique now

-closing all other application on my laptop and then running the merge-Still fails

-executing gc() and then running merge

I have gone through similar questions on SO for R, however none of them offered a solution to move forward and not specific to merges failing on a 64 bit machine

Can anyone please help in either suggesting a solution or a workaround to move forward.

Please assume that this is the only machine where i can execute the code and running this R script on AWS via zepplin is not possible at the moment.

Comment: `data.table` is a great package for working with and merging large datasets

Comment: When you say you have unique rows, does that also mean `length(unique(TrainWithAppevents_rel4$app_id)) == nrow(TrainWithAppevents_rel4)` and `length(unique(app_labels$app_id)) == nrow(app_labels)`?

Comment: Are `device_id` and `app_id` stored as integers? or have they overrun to `double`?

Comment: With that much data, you might consider putting it into a database. It's fairly straight-forward to run postgres, sqlserver, mariadb, or similar on a docker instance on windows, and your joins (if done correctly) will likely be more efficient.

Comment: @StephenHenderson-Following are the data types on the first dataset  :::       $ app_id      : num  4.35e+18 2.76e+18 -8.76e+18 -4.36e+18 8.69e+18                                                                             $ device_id   : num  1.48e+18 1.48e+18 1.48e+18 1.48e+18 1.48e+18 ...

Comment: @BrianStamper-No Combination of Device id +App_id is unique in the first set :::> length(unique(TrainWithAppevents_rel4$app_id))
[1] 6913
> length(unique(app_labels$app_id))
[1] 108162    and in 2nd dataset -app_id can belong to many label_id ie one to many

Comment: @r2evans-That's a good idea but i was hoping to get a solution on handling this in R itself,how is R dealing with large datasets

Comment: You could try `dplyr::filter` rather than merge `temp<-filter(TrainWithAppevents_rel4, app_id %in% app_labels$app_id)`. Then join the smaller `temp` with `app_labels`. My hypothesis is that `filter` will work through the data row by row rather than make a big copy but I'm not sure....

Comment: @StephenHenderson    Wow !!!!                                                
   temp<-filter(TrainWithAppevents_rel4, app_id %in% app_label_categories$app_id)
TrainWithLabels=left_join(temp,app_label_categories,by="app_id")  This Worked !! what just happened here

Comment: @Bak_was It passes through the big data object and just picks out the smaller matches (filter). `merge` probably tries to make another copy of the whole thing. Also don't discount the suggestion to put your data into SQL database. The `dplyr` packages work directly on database tables as if they are data.frames and with `inner_join` will make merges in the database.